# Is it possible to EXEC a T-SQL stored procedure that has an ouput parameter while ignoring SELECT statement?

Tags: t-sql

I am calling one stored procedure from another, and the procedure I am calling has an output parameter.  I am then piping the output value into a local variable.  That's all well and good, but the problem is that this procedure also has a `select` statement in it, so when I `exec`, the results of the procedure are being returned in the final results set.

Is there a way to simply get the value of the output parameter, and ignore everything else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While technically yes, you shouldn't do it. The engine consumes resources to produce the result set you ignore. You may also produce unnecessary contention. If you don't need the result set, you need another procedure that should only produce the output you desire.

Comment: I figured as much.  The SP is only returning 4 columns, so creating another SP or even a function that does exactly the same thing as the current procedure just to ignore a couple of columns seems like a waste.  But I may not have a choice.

Comment: How's about adding an extra parameter to that procedure that allows you to suppress the resultset?  `@SuppressResults BIT = 0`?

Comment: I thought about that approach, but I don't want to have to adjust the existing procedure.  Not to mention that it is already in PROD, and making any adjustments would be a headache. READ: the auditors don't like it.

Comment: You say in the OP the procedure produces a result set and output parameters and you want to ignore the result set. That is fundamentally different from 'ignoring a couple of columns'.

Comment: @Jaden - What's worse, adding a new parameter with a default value and an IF block, or taking a copy of the existing sproc and adjusting it a bit for this purpose?  From a maintainability standpoint I would seriously consider adding the new parameter.

Comment: Because the result set (minus the output parameter) is just a couple of columns.  The procedure itself is doing a lot of work, but what it sends back from the SELECT is minimal.

Comment: Will A - I agree in theory.  I was just hoping there was a quick and dirty way to do this.

Comment: @Jaden - perhaps my #temp table approach is quick 'n' dirty enough?  It is dirty, quick to implement, but not necessarily all that quick to execute.

Comment: From a pragmatic POV it really depends on how much from that 'lot of work' is required for the (ignored) result set, but not for the output parameter. If the procedure does 'lot of work' and at the very end has a `SELECT @somevar, @othervar` then ignoring the result set as Will suggests via a `insert ... exec` is acceptable as a short term hack. But if the 'lot of work' is, say, 50% comprised from the final SELECT itself, then avoiding that 50% is worth going the extra mile.

Comment: Okay, let me revise: Quick and dirty and fast.  Yeah, not gonna happen it looks like.

Comment: @Jaden - how large is your resultset and how complex is your final SELECT?

Comment: The SELECT itself isn't complex at all and sends back a single row with 4 columns. The output parm returns a bit.  I will probably just strip out what I need and create a new function.

Comment: @Jaden - sounds like #temp may be quick, dirty and fast enough.  Maybe.

Comment: 'single row with 4 columns' doesn't say anything about the cost of the SELECT. I can write a `SELECT SUM(...) FROM A JOIN B ON 1=1` that would take hours to produce that one single row...

Comment: Minimal cost.  But for what I am needing, the procedure is doing other processing that I don't need.  It's probably better just to strip out what I need.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there are some tricks for doing this - but the obvious solution that springs to mind is:

```
INSERT INTO #my_rubbish_temp_table_that_i_CREATEd_earlier
  EXEC dbo.mySproc @a, @b, @c OUTPUT
```

...as per Remus' response, this is a waste of CPU, I/O, etc.

If you can add an additional parameter to your stored procedure that allows the suppression of the resultset, that'd be grand.